# Get form data in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to rails and didin't find a soloution after a lot of research...

I want to build a simple data abstaraction test app. I have a text field and a submit button and I want to do something with the input (like ie. `.upcase` ) and then print it out. On submit, I get a routing error, though.

What am I doing wrong?

application.html.erb

```
<body>
<%= form_tag("parse_input", method: "post") do %>
<%= text_field(:ans, :field) %>
<%= submit_tag("submit" %>
<% end %>
```

FormControllerController.rb

```
class FormControllerController < ApplicationController
def parse_input
params[:ans].each do |value|
puts value
end
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
root :to => 'application#home'
get "application" => "form_controller_controller"
end
```

I don't want to use a DB btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
  root :to => 'application#home'
  post "parse_input" => "form_controller_controller#parse_input"
end
```

## application.html.erb

```
<body>
<%= form_tag("/parse_input") do %>
  <%= text_field(:ans, :field) %>
  <%= submit_tag("submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! The routes are fixed.